# Installing Rmpi on Ubuntu 16.04 VirtualBox

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mpi, ubuntu-16.04, openmpi

I created a new ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64 machine on VM VirtualBox and I want to be able to use the R environment with Rmpi.

Both of the below approaches gives a similar error.

**Updated simplified pre-build binary approach:**

When Ubuntu had installed I opened a terminal and executed the following commands:

```
~$ sudo apt-get update
~$ sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin
~$ sudo apt-get install r-base
~$ sudo apt-get install r-cran-rmpi
~$ R
```

This opened the R terminal and I invoking the follow function which resulted in an error:

```
> library(Rmpi)
libmpi.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rmpi', details:
call: fun(libname, pkgname)
error: Cannot start MPI_Init(). Exit
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rmpi’
```

Alternative approaches that I have attempted include using a local OpenMPI installation and using the R function `install.packages` to install the Rmpi package (see below). These all resulted in the same error.

I have also tried using MPICH by substituting `~$ sudo apt-get install mpich` as the second command in the above procedure (including using the R function for installing the package) which results in an even more onerous runtime error.

Does anyone know what I have done wrong or what I can do to resolve this installation error?

Or alternatively, have anyone been able to successfully install a VirtualBox machine with Rmpi using any Linux distro or an image with pre-installed components?

***Original local installation approach:***

I have followed the instructions on [this blog](http://jovingelabsoftware.github.io/blog/2016/02/15/installing-openmpi-and-rmpi-from-source/) to download OpenMPI version 2.1.0, compile and install it. However when I try to install the package in R with:

```
> install.packages("Rmpi", configure.args =
  c("--with-Rmpi-include=/home/jormunr/openmpi/include",
    "--with-Rmpi-libpath=/home/jormunr/openmpi/lib",
    "--with-Rmpi-type=OPENMPI",
    "--with-mpi=/home/jormunr/openmpi/"))
```

it gives the following error

```
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rmpi', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/home/jormunr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rmpi/libs/Rmpi.so':
libmpi.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

I can see that the 'libmpi.so.20' file is in the /home/jormunr/openmpi/lib that I provided as one of the parameter to the installation.

Comment: Do `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rmpi` as we do  have Rmpi as a prebuilt binary.  If you must use a local OpenMPI installation check the autoconf code.

Comment: Do `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/jormunr/openmpi/lib:$LD_LIBRARYP_PATH` before you start R. You can put this in your shell's startup file too. It will allow the run-time link editor to find the MPI library.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - thanks for your comment. I'm very happy to use the prebuild binary. I tried to use the 'sudo apt-get install r-cran-rmpi' to get the binary but when I got into R and loaded it with 'library(Rmpi)' then I got the same error:
libmpi.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rmpi', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: Cannot start MPI_Init(). Exit
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rmpi’

Comment: @HristoIliev - thanks for your comment. I tried to execute the export statement in the terminal before starting R and loading the Rmpi library. This gave a horrible looking error: *** caught segfault *** address 0x1, cause 'memory not mapped' This was followed by a long traceback of function calls.

Comment: Dirk & Hristo - do you think it might be easier to use another Linux distro in VM VirtualBox, e.g. 32 bit ubuntu, ubuntu 14.4 or other Linux flavour? Also, although the online consensus seems to be for OpenMPI, I have also tried MPICH which seems to default to v1 which does not have spawn support even when I specify MPICH2 as configure argument. My end goal is to have a working R sandbox (preferably also RStudio) with Rmpi and process spawn support for an MSc dissertation looking into parallel/distributed facilities of R. Your help and suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: That error could happen if you have code compiled against MPICH that you are trying to execute with Open MPI. Both MPI implementations use different way of expressing constants like `MPI_COMM_WORLD` and are binary incompatible. Make sure all software is compiled with the same MPI implementation. Also, just install MPI from the package system of your Linux distribution.

Comment: You can really run it in a virtual machine. You might even be able to find premade virtual machine images with all that software.

Comment: @HristoIliev – thanks for your comment. To eliminate any errors that could have been caused by previous installations I have created a brand new ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64 VirtualBox and followed the prebuild binary installation route suggested by Dirk. I opened a terminal and only executed the following 4 commands: `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin`, `sudo apt-get install r-base` and `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rmpi`. Then I opened R through the terminal with the command `R` and executed the statement `library(Rmpi)`. This resulted in the same error as above.

Comment: In the spirit of thoroughness I have just tried with MPICH in a brand new ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64 VirtualBox. I followed the same process as above with the exception of executing `sudo apt-get install mpich` as the second command. All other steps were the same but this still resulted in an long complicated-looking and fatal error.

Comment: @HristoIliev - do you have any links to someone setting up a VirtualBox with Rmpi? Or do you have links to virtual images that comes with RStudio and Rmpi pre-installed?

Comment: The problem is that you want OpenMPI 2.* whereas all the packaging is still done with MPI 1.*.  So you can't rely on the packages, and it doesn't matter whether you do it at the direct level of the OS, or in a virtual machine of basically the same OS hosted on the same OS.

Comment: On my machine---running Ubuntu 16.10---the `r-cran-rmpi` package just works.  But it is linked against package `libopenmpi1.10`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - thanks a lot for your comment. How would I go about linking Rmpi against libopenmpi1.10? If libopenmpi1.10 supports spawning that version would be great for my purposes. I am not a Linux expert - I amended the second command in the above procedure to `sudo apt-get install libopenmpi1.10` and follow the rest of the steps but got the same error.

Comment: You seem to be lost at high sea, and I *strongly* recommend you seek help from a local expert at your institution.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel – unfortunately that is not an option, I have tried but they are not supporting. I'm not a novice and been using both R and Linux successfully for some time. Is there no website or other places that would be able help? My frustration is that all the websites I have found seems to think it is really straight forward to install Rmpi (the complication seems to be to understand MPI communication and parallel computation). Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: My frustration is that other packages can be installed with a simple one line command, e.g. `install.packages("*")` function in R or by `sudo apt-get install r-cran-*` from the terminal. Am I missing something or why is that not the case for Rmpi?

Comment: Hallelujah!!! Finally found a solution!!! Have now spent the whole week finding out how to install Rmpi, I now deserve a drink – a very big one!!! I will update with an answer when I'm sober! That might not be until Monday!

Answer (score 2):

[Disclaimer: I am not a Linux expert and merely have user level skills. Any contributions or corrections from an expert will be greatly appreciated.]

**Pre-build Binary Approach**

Although trying various ways to install the prebuilt binaries I did not manage to get this option to work. This involved executing in the terminal the command 'sudo apt-get install r-cran-rmpi' to install the r-cran-rmpi prebuilt packages which also automatically installs the libopenmpi1.10 package that is a listed prerequisite. However, it appears that the file 'libmpi.so' is not included in the libopenmpi1.10 package but expected by the Rmpi library which causes an error in the R environment that it cannot find this file.

**Local Installation Approach**

The local installation did eventually succeed with a few amendments. I created a new ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64 VirtualBox image with default settings, except for 2048MB of memory and 32GB of hard drive space. When installed I opened a terminal and executed the commands from [the Jovinge Lab website](http://jovingelabsoftware.github.io/blog/2016/02/15/installing-openmpi-and-rmpi-from-source/) with the inclusion of the penultimate command which amends the run-time link editor's path and enables the install.package() function of R to find the 'libmpi.so' file. (also changed the version to 1.10.6 as this is the latest version release of version 1 – see below for version 2)

```
~$ cd /home/jormunr
~$ wget https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v1.10/downloads/openmpi-1.10.2.tar.gz
~$ tar -zxvf openmpi-1.10.6.tar.gz
~$ cd openmpi-1.10.2
~$ ./configure --prefix=/home/jormunr
~$ make
~$ make install
~$ sudo apt-get install r-base
~$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/jormunr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
~$ R
```

This opens an R terminal and I invoked the function:

```
> install.packages("Rmpi", configure.args =
+ c("--with-Rmpi-include=/home/jormunr/include/",
+   "--with-Rmpi-libpath=/home/jormunr/lib/",
+   "--with-Rmpi-type=OPENMPI",
+   "--with-mpi=/home/jormunr/"))
```

This now executed without errors and I could test it with the following R statements:

```
> library("Rmpi")
> mpi.spawn.Rslaves()
master (rank 0, comm. 1) of size 2 is running on: Valhalla
slave1 (rank 1, comm. 1) of size 2 is running on: Valhalla
> mpi.close.Rslaves()
[1] 1
> mpi.quit()
```

When I tried this process with the OpenMPI Version 2.1.0 the installation completed successfully but the above test had issues; the mpi.spawn.Rslaves() function completed but mpi.close.Rslaves() did not complete – it never returned and the terminal was left hanging.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar challenges. I landed on this solution where libopenmpi-dev was the secret.

```
sudo apt-get install openmpi-common openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev r-base
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rmpi
sudo su
R
install.packages("doMPI", dependencies=TRUE)
```